# Errors when typing the correct username and password

Tags: php, mysql, http-headers

I've been looking up these two different errors but I can't find a resolution to mine from the previous questions. I have a log in form and every time you type the correct username and password it throws these two errors...

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home4/jedicody/public_html/LR/core/functions/users.php on line 96
>
> `` $data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id")); ``

and

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home4/jedicody/public_html/LR/core/functions/users.php:96) in /home4/jedicody/public_html/LR/core/init.php on line 17
>
> `header('Location: index.php');`

These are the lines of code it doesn't like. I can give you any other piece of information you need from my code but was wondering if anyone could give me some insight on what I'm doing wrong. Thank you guys very much in advance for taking a look.

Comment: You are not getting a result from the database. Your query is wrong, or the username and password don't match. It is as simple as that. Echo the query that is being run to the screen and copy and paste it into something like phpmyadmin and test that is it getting what you want.

Comment: Perhaps if you are doing it by username and password, you want to do the WHERE not with the user_id, but as WHERE username = 'etc';

Comment: You should be wrapping `$user_id` in quotes : `WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id'`

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses, I'm double checking my query now and will update you in a moment.

Comment: You should check the return value of `mysql_query()`. If it's `false`, `echo mysql_error()` to see the reason for the failure.

Answer (score 0):

You can echo your sql sentence and execute it in phpmyadmin or mysql console to see if there's something wrong in the result.

Comment: Okay I've typed my query in phpmyadmin and this is what I've wrote.. 
SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id


This is what I get.

#1054 - Unknown column '$fields' in 'field list'

Comment: You should echo this:"SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id" in your php programe, then you will get a sentence in your web browser, like:"SELECT xxx FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = 30" and put this one in your phpmyadmin to execute. [$field is a variable in you php, it can not be recognized in mysql]